# Calling function inside a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Hi everyone, I'm learning JS and trying to practice using a function inside a function. So, I've come up with my own problem to code. I understand that there's an easier way to do this and the problem could've been written better, but for the purpose of practicing, this is what I've come up with:

John is 13 years old. Write a function to find out what year John was born, and what school type he is attending BASED ON his birth year -- high school or middle school.

Middle school = 2003 - 2004
High school = 1999 - 2002

```
function calculateBirthYearJohn(ageJohn) {
    var currentYear = 2017;
    var birthYearJohn = currentYear - ageJohn;
    return birthYearJohn;
}

function defineSchoolTypeJohn(birthYear) {
    var birthYear = calculateBirthYearJohn(ageJohn);
    if (birthYear >= 2003 & <= 2004) {
        console.log('John goes to Middle School.');
    } else if (birthYear >= 1999 & <= 2002) {
        console.log('John goes to High School.');
    }
}
```

Console will say "John goes to Middle School" if he's born between 2003 and 2004; "John goes to High School" if he's born between 1999 and 2002.

Blank result -- no error.

I've made a newbie mistake somewhere; can someone please point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Comment: `birthYear >= 2003 & <= 2004` --> `birthYear >= 2003 && birthYear <= 2004` and same goes for the other condition

Comment: You should define `function defineSchoolTypeJohn(ageJohn)`, since you try to get `birthYear` from `ageJohn`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple problems.

line 8: `ageJohn == undefined`

lines 9 and 11: In JavaScript, `&&` is the [Logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator (two ampersands). One singular ampersand is the [Bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) operator. Also, comparison only works between two variables at a time, hence, your attempt to chain is invalid.

See below for a working example.

```js
function calculateBirthYear(ageJohn) {
    const currentYear = 2017
    const birthYear = currentYear - ageJohn
    return birthYear
}

function defineSchoolType(ageJohn) {
    const birthYear = calculateBirthYear(ageJohn)
    if (birthYear >= 2003 && birthYear <= 2004) console.log('John goes to Middle School.') 
    else if (birthYear >= 1999 && birthYear <= 2002) console.log('John goes to High School.')
    else console.log('John doesn\'t go to Middle School or High School')
}

defineSchoolType(13) // Middle School.
defineSchoolType(15) // High School.
defineSchoolType(20) // Neither.
```

Comment: Thank you. Learning as I identify and correct my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
var birthyear = calculateBirthYear(ageJohn);
```

but you have not defined `ageJohn` anywhere. Up in `calculateBirthYear`, you gave it as the argument, but that is not the same as a variable that can be accessed anywhere. I think you meant to write:

```
function defineSchoolTypeJohn(ageJohn) {
    var birthYear = calculateBirthYear(ageJohn);
    ...
```

Now, you have defined `ageJohn` as the argument to the function.